# Does Kerberos support vendor specific attributes?

Tags: kerberos

As the question title says: Does Kerberos support vendor specific attributes allowing access segmentation within a given client device?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?  I am used to Kerberos using the term "attributes" to identify flags set on principals in the realm/database.  What do you mean by access segmentation within a device, and are you really trying to do this via attribute flags on principals?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has no SDK/API to change the kerberos protocol, and it wouldn't be a small feat to reimplement kerberos on both sides (client and server) as an authentication package.

I think you are missing a key point with your use case, kerberos is an authentication protocol, as such it should **only** deal with checking that you are who you say you are, network location isn't part of that.
what you require is authorization, this is abstracted away from kerberos as a security measure and it is a bad idea to change that.

what you can do is change the authorization part - on the Domain Controller you can decide which user is allowed to login to which computer (or a OU of devices) using [group policy](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=53314). if this is for your specific application you can always implement it at that level.

another way is to create a site per subnet and allow logon to each user per site. look [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b4fdd257-75f6-4968-80fd-d995c3ee00ac/restrict-logon-by-subnet-not-computer-name?forum=winservergen).